# JQuery Preview Form when Review Button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to preview a form before the customer submits. I have one fieldset that shows form, then the user can preview there entries on another fieldset before they submit there form.

Thanks for all and any help.

I tried this:

```
var fname = $('input#fname').val();
$(field2.show_fname).html(fname).show();
```

But didnt work at all.

Code is below. Here is my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xdmp8zz4/3/

HTML:

```
<form id="helpdeskform" action="process.php" method="post">
    <fieldset class="field1 current">
        <h2>(Placeholder) Title of Form heading level 2</h2>
            <p><label class="form-label first-name" for="fname">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name"/>
            </p>
            <p><label class="form-label last-name" for="lname">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
            </p>
            <p><label class="form-label" for="phone-field">Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone-field" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
            </p>
             <p><label class="form-label" for="email-field">E-mail:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email-field" placeholder="E-mail"/>
            </p>        
            <hr>
            <p><label for="classify">Type of Request:</label>
                <select name="classify" id="classify">
                    <option value="select">Please select an option..</option>
                    <option value="maintainence">Maintainence of Site</option>
                    <option value="troubleshoot">Troubleshoot/Error</option>
                    <option value="new">Create new content</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p><label for="subject">Short Description: <span class="counter-field"><span id="counter"></span> characters left.</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject"/>
            </p>
            <p><label for="desc">Additional Comments:</label>
                <textarea style="font-family: Arial, Veranda, Sans serif" name="desc" id="desc" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Short Description"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p><label for="review">
                <input type="button" name="review" class="review action-button" value="Review"/>
            </label></p>            
  </fieldset>   

    <fieldset class="field2">
    <!-- @TODO PREVIEW ALL FORM INPUTS -->
            <p>First Name: <input type="hidden" class="show_fname" readonly="readonly" /></p>
            <p>Last Name: <input type="hidden" class="show_lname" readonly="readonly" /></p>
            <p>Phone: <input type="hidden" class="show_phone" readonly="readonly" /></p>
            <p>E-mail: <input type="hidden" class="show_email" readonly="readonly" /></p>
            <p>Type of Request: <input type="hidden" class="show_type_of_request" readonly="readonly" /></p>
            <p>Short Description: <input type="hidden" class="show_subject" readonly="readonly" /></p>
            <p>Additional Comments: <input type="hidden" class="show_comments" readonly="readonly" /></p>
            <p style="float:left;"><label for="previous">
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous"/>
            </label></p>
            <p style="float:left; padding-left: 10px;"><label for="Submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="action-button"/>
            </label></p>
  </fieldset>                                                                        
  </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.review').click(function () {
        $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');

    });

    $('.previous').click(function () {
        $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().prev().show().addClass('current');

    });

    $('#subject').simplyCountable({
        counter:            '#counter',
        countType:          'characters',
        maxCount:           80,
        strictMax:          true,
        countDirection:     'down',
    });

    });
```

CSS:

```
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#helpdeskform .field2 {
    display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#helpdeskform input {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#helpdeskform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}

/*buttons*/
#helpdeskform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
#helpdeskform .action-button:hover, 
#helpdeskform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #900;
}

/*Form labels*/
label.form-label {
    text-align: left;
}

/*Phone Label Align*/
input#phone-field {
    margin-left: 26px;
}

/*E-mail Label Align*/
input#email-field {
    margin-left: 24px;
}

.counter-field {
    font-size: 10px;
}
/*Divider*/
hr {
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 0px;
border-width: 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the text inputs in the second fieldset to hidden won't allow you to set the value and also won't display. I've changed these to `type="text"`and set things up to loop through the form values in the first to set all the form values in the review section here, http://jsfiddle.net/xdmp8zz4/23/

Comment: This works perfectly. I cant believe I had the fields as hidden. DUH! Thanks for pointing this out to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for the first name one to show up in the review.

```
$('.show_fname').after($('#fname').val());
```

You can't put the value in the hidden input because it is hidden, and you can't change the type of the input from hidden to text because jQuery forbids it. Either you can change the input from hidden to text/disabled or you can simply place it in html as I have done with the simple code above.